# iOS 7 Simulator vs Real iPhone unexplained differences

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, simulator, ios7

I am working on a fix for iOS 7 and having a problem. When I run my app on real device (iPhone 4S iOS 7), the screen looks different than when I run the same app on iPhone 3.5 inches iOS 7 Simulator. I am trying to understand why and what is the reason for that, if anyone can help it would be great!

First screenshot from Simulator, second picture from Device:

**SOLVED:** The app on the real iPhone has a base SDK 6.0 and the app that is on the Simulator has base SDK 7.0. So I guess the real device knew how to compensate for the low SDK base, unlike the simulator which behaved totally in a SDK 7.0 environment and thats why it was showing differently. thanks!

[image: SIMULATOR:]

[image: REAL DEVICE:]

Comment: Look at your interface builder. There is a property "Extend edges" in the attributes inspectors. Try to change the under top bars to see if it looks better. Also, try to change the "size" property in the same tab.

Comment: Hey! I couldn't find this property. But I want to understand correctly: that means, that what ever I see on my device is the "real" way the app looks? and basically, this property is only for the simulator?

Comment: iPhone 4S is a 4" screen, and your app will look different on a 3.5". The tab I'm talking about is the 4th of the right menu (after you select your view controller). The solution to your problem is to change the "Size" option to 3.5, and to change what you need to change :)

Comment: I truly appreciate your comments and help but according to what I know, iPhone 4 has 3.5 screen and iPhone 5 is the one who has 4 inches screen. See reference: [Apple iPhones Deatils](http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/).

I still don't get why the simulator is different from the device.

Comment: iPhone 4S is a 3.5" screen and it will look different on the iPhone 5's 4" screen

Comment: The situation is that I am very confused, because in one hand, the simulator should give us an accurate idea of how the app will look on real device. But on the other hand, in my case, the real device shows something different than the simulator, so which is wrong and why? anyone?

Comment: @RoyKronenfeld is there a better solution?  I'm having this issue as well, and I was wondering if all devices behave this way or will there be a point (or is there a specific device) where it'll use fully the iOS 7 base SDK, and it'll behave just like in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else reading this, Roy's 'Solved' comment above is correct.

I have gone into Xcode after the update and it had automatically updated my Base SDK to the latest 'iOS 7.0'.

After changing this back to 'iOS 6.1' - both the Simulator and Device are now working the same, as expected on iOS 7.

Not trying to steal Roy's thunder (whose saved me a good numbers of hours - thank you), just summarizing to others how to quickly fix the issue.

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the proposed solution, Apple Documentation recommends to set Base SDK to the latest iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW37, so there must be a better solution

Comment: So it does. If I revert my project back to Latest iOS 7.0 - this behaviour starts all over again. Perhaps this is a testing issue but I am not confident enough to release my App to the App store as Apple suggest - All very strange! If anyone has an update on this it would be of great interest.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue..

I solved by adding below code at viewDidLoad method..of view controller.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Hope it helps..Thanks.